# Inequality beetwen $\cos(t)$ and $\frac{\sin(t)}{t}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

How do I prove the following inequality:
$$\cos(t) \leq \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\sin(t)}{t}, \;\;\; \forall\;\;t \in (0, \pi/4].$$

*Attempt:* I considered the function $f(t)=  \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\sin(t)}{t} -  \cos(t)$, in which its derivative is
$$f'(t) = \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{(t-t^2)\cos(t) - \sin(t)}{t^2}$$
and its needed to be proved that $f \geq 0$ in the interval $(0, \pi/4]$. How do I deal with this derivative?? How do I analyze the sign of the derivative??

Comment: It might be helpful to observe that $\tan {t}$ lies above the line $y=2t/\pi$ for $t$ in $(0, \pi/4)$ and they intersect at $t=0$

Comment: I would multiply by $t$ first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is equivalent to $\tan t\ge\tfrac{2t}{\pi}$. In fact, the stronger inequality $\tan t\ge t$ is famously correct for all acute $t$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint : Show that $\sin(t) \geq \dfrac{2t}{\pi}$ if $0\leq t \leq \dfrac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

The inequality is equivalent to $$\tan x \ge \frac{2x}{\pi}, x \in (0,\pi/4]$$
Let $$f(x)=\tan(x)\frac{2x}{\pi} \implies f'(x)=\sec^2x-\frac{2}{\pi}>0$$
So $f(x)$ is increasing in $(0,\pi/4]$, hence $$f(x)\ge f(0)=0 \implies \tan x \ge \frac{2x}{\pi}$$